# Size and kind of wire required to go from main panel to garage 400 ft away

Tags: electrical, wiring

What kind and size wire do I need to run underground, from the main panel in the house to a garage 400 ft away, to get 60 AMPS (usable) at the sub panel in the garage?

Comment: Have you tried searching the site? I'm pretty sure this question has been asked before.

Comment: Don't forget to call the building department... sometimes subpanels require inspection.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a voltage [drop calculator](http://www.southwire.com/support/voltage-drop-calculator.htm). It came up with 1 conductors per phase utilizing a #1 Copper conductor will limit the voltage drop to 2.97% or less when supplying 60.0 amps for 400 feet on a 240 volt system.
The type depends on how you are going to install it. UF (underground feeder) type wire for direct burial, or if in conduit THWN. Also the minimum burial depth is 18" per NEC table 300.5.